# Page with redirect

Tags: plugins, loop, redirect, seo

I have an issue with indexing my website, where I get "Page with redirect" error on GSC or " Redirect loop", also on Yandex ( Yandex says **The rel="canonical" attribute in the page's source code points to the same page.** so when I tried a [httpstatus](https://httpstatus.io/) tool to look an see the error with [my website](https://psdshelf.com) I found out that there are several errors as seen below, please can someone tell me how can I fix it, or is even a problem, because I fear that It's affecting the indexing of my blog, because it's been almost a year that the website is online, and only 11 pages are indexed even while I'm doing my best with SEO.
thanks
[image: Issues I found with my link redirect]

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: Your image doesn't appear to show any errors. Assuming you want the `https://example.com` version indexed, not the `http` version or the `www` version, those other versions are successfully redirecting to the one version you want indexed. It may help you to do a `site:example.com` query in a search engine to see what URLs they have indexed. Having a website online for one year is a relatively short timeframe in comparison to many sites, so you may have to wait longer to see higher rankings.

Comment: Well, thanks @WebElaine that's a bit reassuring since I'm getting the same message on GSC, so thanks a lot. Much appreciated.